# Getting undefined whilst trying to use object literals

Tags: javascript, object

Quick breakdown of my scenario.

I am building a website which allows users to customise a door. On this page they can change the frame (and color but I'll worry about that later).

I have a few object literals. One storing information about the current door, and one for each frame type (holding things such as a link to images, cost etc).

The problem is when I try to update the object literal concerning the current door. I keep getting "undefined" whilst querying the frame object literals.

I have a function which accepts an ID (of a frame) to change the current frame.

```
function changeFrame(id){
    currentDoor.frameImage = id.frameImgLink;
}
```

However if I run this code I keep getting door.frame set to "undefined." Any time I am trying to access the object literals through id.x I keep getting "undefined" returned.

If anyone has any pointers this would be greatly appreciated.

I can post more code if need be, I don't think it would be required, however I can post if requested. Thanks.

Comment: Is "id" an object or a primitive (e.g. an integer)?  If it's an integer, it won't have any properties.  Have you tried using something like the Chrome Developer Tools, and putting a breakpoint at that line in your program to see what the value of id is?  Or even just console.log(id)?

Comment: Nothing is inherently wrong with the code snippet you've provided. The error is coming from somewhere else in your code (which we have no idea what that could be). Could you please provide some other relevant parts of your code?

Comment: @Cully ID is a string (it's a frame name, so "Leftsidepanel" for instance). I used console.log and the breakpoints and I keep getting "undefined" returned when I query the current door literal that I've changed for ID. ID correctly evaluates inside my function (to for instance "Leftsidepanel" and so on so I'm confused).

Josh I understand, I'll paste my code here for anyone to have a quick peak at:

http://pastebin.ca/3081367

If you need any more information fire away. Thanks guys.

Comment: If `id` is a string, then it won't have a `frameImgLink` property.  Is the value of `id` the id of a DOM element you're trying to refer to?  So, something more like:  `var myElement = document.getElementById(id); console.log(myElement);` ???

Comment: Sorry Cully I should have made myself more clear. It's a strong literal. From the code:                                             var Leftsidepanel = {
    name: "Left sidepanel",
    cost: "200",
    image: "frame_with_side_panel_white.png",
    minwidth: "900",
    minheight: "1500",
    maxwidth: "",
    maxheight: "",
    description: "A sidepanel to the left of the door",
}